# html css what is the modern line?

Tags: html, css

What is the modern way of making a line half way across the screen? I saw this in a tutorial and it looks a bit old fashioned now.

Like:

```
<hr size="6" width="50%">
```

How would you do something similar if you were making a webpage now?

Comment: No, it's not. This should be controlled with styles. Example below

Comment: @Alex why SHOULD it be controlled with styles? OP just wants to draw a line on half of the screen width. He did not request any special styling except that.

Comment: Best practice. Easier to maintain. Easier to change. True, his method will work, but why tell someone to do it in a manner that will only work for one particular element?

Comment: @Or W: Because, apparently, [the spec says so](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.3) (notice **every** possible attribute is deprecated and happens to be a CSS-controllable attribute).

Comment: @Or W: if the OP wants to draw not one, but twenty such lines, writing the HTML attributes for each one is a pain. In CSS, you can use one declaration to control everything.

Comment: @OrW, inline styles override those defined in style sheets. That includes the user style sheet. Inline styles should be avoided in production.

Comment: @Or W - "width" implies style ;) They're also asking about the "modern" way to do it, and the `width` attribute is deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can continue to use `<hr />`, but I would suggest omitting the inline attributes. It is just another element, and you can move your styling information to css:

```
hr {
  width:50%; 
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: in which cases (browsers?) does the margin declaration become necessary?

Comment: @mingos I have no idea; I explicitly center-align elements I want to be center-aligned, just in case. It's probably not worth including, actually.

Comment: @Trufa: I disagree. See the comments under the original post.

Comment: @mingos I stand corrected! Thanks for that, I deleted my comment to avoid confusion!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS to style the line](http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html)

```
hr{
   width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<hr />
```

CSS:

```
hr { width: 50%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be controlled in CSS using something like:

`hr {
   width: 50%;
}`

You can change borders etc too. Just make sure you reset the borders and backgrounds as different browsers use different methods to style it

Answer (score -1):

Using a `<div>` and some styling:

```
#line {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Centered */
    height: 4px; /* The border adds to height */
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    border-right: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
}
```

Comment: `<hr>` is certainly more appropriate than `<div>`

Comment: You can hammer nails with a stone, but what's the use when you have a hammer at hand? ;)

Comment: @mingos: But a hammer head is merely refined metal which comes from ore (OK, you can hit me).

Comment: Beer is also only processed malt, hops and yeast - but we still have beer at parties, don't we? ;)

Comment: Ok someone got the joke :) It's like killing an ant with a cannon.